# The screen is too small⠀

Tags: screen, display-resolution

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04, but the screen is simply too small. (The screen is an old Samsung TV.) I just see half of the launcher, and the panel is missing. I've tried to change the resolution, but it's just the same all the time. I also tried different drivers. I'm not an experienced Ubuntu user.

These are the results of running `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 720, macimum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
 160mm x 90mm
   1280x720       50.0*+    60.0    59.9
   1920x1080      60.1      60.0    50.0
   720x576        50.0
   720x480        59.9
   640x480        59.9
```

Can anyone help? What can I try next?

Comment: please run the command `xrandr` in a terminal and edit your question to add the output.